# GetElementByClassName GO WITH I.E 7

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry to follow this topic

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044825/javascript-run-on-ie-7
```

I want to use document.GetElementByClassName ON INTERNET EXPLORE 7

After i download the below js file and Paste it to my code

```
http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/
```

Here is my code

```
<script>
var getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            elm = elm || document;
            var elements = elm.getElementsByClassName(className),
                nodeName = (tag)? new RegExp("\\b" + tag + "\\b", "i") : null,
                returnElements = [],
                current;
            for(var i=0, il=elements.length; i<il; i+=1){
                current = elements[i];
                if(!nodeName || nodeName.test(current.nodeName)) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else if (document.evaluate) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = "",
                xhtmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
                namespaceResolver = (document.documentElement.namespaceURI === xhtmlNamespace)? xhtmlNamespace : null,
                returnElements = [],
                elements,
                node;
            for(var j=0, jl=classes.length; j<jl; j+=1){
                classesToCheck += "[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + classes[j] + " ')]";
            }
            try {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, namespaceResolver, 0, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, null, 0, null);
            }
            while ((node = elements.iterateNext())) {
                returnElements.push(node);
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = [],
                elements = (tag === "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag),
                current,
                returnElements = [],
                match;
            for(var k=0, kl=classes.length; k<kl; k+=1){
                classesToCheck.push(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classes[k] + "(\\s|$)"));
            }
            for(var l=0, ll=elements.length; l<ll; l+=1){
                current = elements[l];
                match = false;
                for(var m=0, ml=classesToCheck.length; m<ml; m+=1){
                    match = classesToCheck[m].test(current.className);
                    if (!match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    return getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm);
};
```

And call the getElemeentsByClassName Function

```
   var list = document.getElementsByClassName("count_regulation");
for (var i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
    list[i].innerHTML = i;
}
```

Still have no effect on IE 7 --  . Please explain which part i wrong when i use the js because i am newbie of Javascripts. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `document`:

```
var list = /*no document here*/getElementsByClassName("count_regulation");
for (var i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
   list[i].innerHTML = i;
}
```