# How to make a pattern of div elements

Tags: html, css

What is the most efficient way to make a pattern of Div elements with incrementing ID's as numbers?

I want to have 56 columns and 80 rows. The first div created in the top left corner would have an id of 1, and the last div created in the bottom right corner would have an id of 4480.

I know I can do:

```
<style>
    .myGrid{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr and so on...;
        grid-gap:5px;
        grid-auto-rows: 50px;
        grid-auto-columns: 50px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class = "myGrid">
        <div class = "gridItem" id = "1"><div>
        <div class = "gridItem" id = "2"><div>
        <div class = "gridItem" id = "3"><div>
        and so on...
    </div>
</body>
```

But this will take 100 years to type out, and I know there must be a better way.

The reason I want the id to increment is that I would like to target them with javascript once I have the grid pattern complete.

Comment: So break out JavaScript and make some elements

Comment: `grid-template-columns:repeat(56,1fr)`maybe ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026311/3536236 is a similar JS solution, you should be able to get the idea from this

Comment: and for the ids :`let gridChild = document.querySelectorAll(".mygrid>div");
for (let i = 0; i < gridChild.length; i++) {gridChild[i].setAttribute('id','grid-' + i);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So make a for loop and start creating elements and add it to the page.

```js
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.className = "myGrid";

var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.className = 'gridItem';
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var copy = elem.cloneNode();
  copy.setAttribute("data-id", i + 1);
  temp.appendChild(copy);
}

document.body.replaceChild(temp, document.querySelector('.myGrid'));
```

```css
.myGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
}

div.gridItem {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.gridItem::after {
  content: attr(data-id);
}
```

```html
<div class="myGrid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the patern of the grid can use the repeat() to set the templates, to increment ids, js will be required:

example :

```js
let gridChild = document.querySelectorAll(".mygrid>div");
for (let i = 0; i < gridChild.length; i++) {
  gridChild[i].setAttribute('id', 'grid-' + i);
}
```

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(56, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(80, 50px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  /*
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px;
  */
  width:max-content;
}


/* show id */

div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

div div:before {
  content: attr(id)
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```